# Batch move gDoc files but they convert to PDF? Why don't they retain mimeType?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

Following code is to move native gDocs from one folder on a drive into another which has subfolders with student names. The original file has a version of the student name and ID which is rearranged by the getSubfolderName. That part works, the only issue is it returns PDF's instead of the original files.

```
function moveFilesToModifiedSubfolders() {
  var sourceFolderId = "source folder"; // Replace with the ID of your source folder
  var destinationFolderId = "destination folder to be modified by sub"; // Replace with the ID of your destination folder
  
  var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(sourceFolderId);
  var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);
  
  var files = sourceFolder.getFiles();
  
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileName = file.getName();
    var subfolderName = getSubfolderName(fileName);
    
    var subfolder = destinationFolder.getFoldersByName(subfolderName);
    if (subfolder.hasNext()) {
       subfolder.next().createFile(file);

    } else {
      var newSubfolder = destinationFolder.createFolder(subfolderName);
        newSubfolder.createFile(file);

      
    }
  }
}
// used to match names to folders in another drive someone else created
function getSubfolderName(fileName) {
  var words = fileName.split(" ");
  if (words.length >= 2) {
    var modifiedName = words[1] + ", " + words[0];
    return modifiedName;
  } else {
    return fileName;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- About your current issue of `the only issue is it returns PDF's instead of the original files.`, I guessed that the reason for this is due to that `createFile` is used for copying the file. In this case, `makeCopy` is required to be used.
- But, from `move native gDocs from one folder on a drive into another which has subfolders with student names.`, if you want to move instead of copy the files, it is required to use `moveTo`.

But, unfortunately, I cannot understand your actual expected result of `move native gDocs from one folder on a drive into another which has subfolders with student names.`. So, in this answer, I would like to propose 2 patterns.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the files are copied. Please modify `moveFilesToModifiedSubfolders` as follows.

```js
function moveFilesToModifiedSubfolders() {
  var sourceFolderId = "source folder"; // Replace with the ID of your source folder
  var destinationFolderId = "destination folder to be modified by sub"; // Replace with the ID of your destination folder
  var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(sourceFolderId);
  var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);
  var files = sourceFolder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileName = file.getName();
    var subfolderName = getSubfolderName(fileName);
    var subfolder = destinationFolder.getFoldersByName(subfolderName);
    if (subfolder.hasNext()) {
      //  subfolder.next().createFile(file);
      file.makeCopy(fileName, subfolder.next());
    } else {
      var newSubfolder = destinationFolder.createFolder(subfolderName);
      // newSubfolder.createFile(file);
      file.makeCopy(fileName, newSubfolder);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the files are moved. Please modify `moveFilesToModifiedSubfolders` as follows.

```js
function moveFilesToModifiedSubfolders() {
  var sourceFolderId = "source folder"; // Replace with the ID of your source folder
  var destinationFolderId = "destination folder to be modified by sub"; // Replace with the ID of your destination folder
  var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(sourceFolderId);
  var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);
  var files = sourceFolder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileName = file.getName();
    var subfolderName = getSubfolderName(fileName);
    var subfolder = destinationFolder.getFoldersByName(subfolderName);
    if (subfolder.hasNext()) {
      //  subfolder.next().createFile(file);
      file.moveTo(subfolder.next());
    } else {
      var newSubfolder = destinationFolder.createFolder(subfolderName);
      // newSubfolder.createFile(file);
      file.moveTo(newSubfolder);
    }
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [makeCopy(name, destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(String,Folder))
- [moveTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#movetodestination)

Comment: Thanks Tanaike, I only tried the first pattern and it worked perfectly. To answer your question, or clarify my request, I just needed to move files from one place to another and organize them into subfolders based on naming convention taken from data parsed in the filename but my original script saved them as PDF even though the original was a google native doc. Thanks!